How to run kong gateway and kong ingress controller in the same cluster
I am trying to set up kong gateway and the ingress controller in an EKS cluster. Both the controller, and the gateway create classic LBs in the cluster.
The problem is that the ingress resources are destroyed and recreated continuously. It will create the resource and point it to the LB of the gateway, then destroy it and create the ingress resource pointing to the controller LB.
I am new to trying to use kong. Please why does the gateway need an LB if the ingress controller has an LB, or how do I disable the gateway LB so that they all use the ingress controller.
I have tried going through docs, but I am not getting any clarity.
My ingress resource
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /
      ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root":"/","ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect":"false","kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"kong"},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"server","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"argocd","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"Helm","app.kubernetes.io/name":"argocd-server","app.kubernetes.io/part-of":"argocd","app.kubernetes.io/version":"v2.9.5","argocd.argoproj.io/instance":"argocd","helm.sh/chart":"argo-cd-5.53.8"},"name":"argocd-server","namespace":"argocd"},"spec":{"ingressClassName":"kong","rules":[{"host":"aws-argocd-stage.tersu.com","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"service":{"name":"argocd-server","port":{"number":443}}},"path":"/","pathType":"Prefix"}]}}]}}
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
    creationTimestamp: "2024-05-03T15:50:49Z"
    generation: 1
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: server
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: argocd
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
      app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
      app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
      app.kubernetes.io/version: v2.9.5
      argocd.argoproj.io/instance: argocd
      helm.sh/chart: argo-cd-5.53.8
    name: argocd-server
    namespace: argocd
    resourceVersion: "39457334"
    uid: 836cb08b-b84e-4fc8-9e1b-176698da9bbd
  spec:
    ingressClassName: kong
    rules:
    - host: aws-argocd-stage.tersu.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: argocd-server
              port:
                number: 443
          path: /
          pathType: Prefix
  status:
    loadBalancer:
      ingress:
      - hostname: XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX.eu-north-1.elb.amazonaws.com
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""

The kong values
deployment:
  test:
    enabled: false

controller:
  proxy:
    nameOverride: "{{ .Release.Name }}-gateway-proxy"

  enabled: true

  deployment:
    kong:
      enabled: false

  ingressController:
    enabled: true

    gatewayDiscovery:
      enabled: true
      generateAdminApiService: true

  podAnnotations:
    kuma.io/gateway: enabled
    # This port must match your Kong admin API port. 8444 is the default.
    # If you set gateway.admin.tls.containerPort, change these annotations
    # to use that value.
    traffic.kuma.io/exclude-outbound-ports: "8444"
    traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts: "8444"

gateway:
  enabled: true
  deployment:
    kong:
      enabled: true

  admin:
    enabled: true
    type: ClusterIP
    clusterIP: None

  ingressController:
    enabled: false

  env:
    role: traditional
    database: "off"

The chart: https://github.com/Kong/charts/blob/main/charts/ingress/README.md
